# Error in Working with Socket When Sending Object Frequently

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, remote-desktop

I'm writing a program that can manage computers in a network environment.

I try to be a part of this program will assign the control of the remote client(Remote Desktop) . but my target is like teamviewer not RDC(RDP) .

i want make a service and put it into Client , that Service running every time (Automatic , Auto Start)

I use sending mouse and keyboard from server to client and screenshot of desktop of client will be transfer to server, the destination computer must control.

i write it by BackgroundWorker in loop ( in Complete_BW i put BW.RunWorkerAsync() )

i use socket and when i run program my server rise error after 1 or 2 times sent desktop image to server , error is in Socket.EndPoint  ...

codes is here :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;


namespace remServer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
        public Image GetImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {
            Image ret = null;
            try
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
                ret = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
            catch { }
            return ret;
        }
        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            FTServerCode f = new FTServerCode();
            Byte[] getCap = f.StartServer();
            img.Image = GetImage(getCap);

        }

        private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    public  class FTServerCode
    {
        IPEndPoint ipEnd;
        Socket sock;
        public FTServerCode()
        {
            try
            {

                ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5656); // Error In this Line
                sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
                sock.Bind(ipEnd);
            }
            catch { }
        }
        public Byte[] StartServer()
        {
            byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 5000];
            try
            {
                sock.Listen(100);

                Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();



                int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);

                clientSock.Close();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File Receving error." + ex.Message);
            }
            return clientData;
        }
    }
}
```

if client code is Necessary tell me to put in here . tnx

Comment: Include a sample of your code and the exact exception message.